# Acceder a mensaje de la respuesta AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, response

**DUDA:**

Con la siguiente repuesta de archivo.php: **(JSON)**

```
{ "status": "errorx", "error": { "code": "error", "message": "El fichero ZIP con las cartas no se ha generado correctamente" } }
```

como desde un archivo js, puedo acceder al "message".

os dejo el ejemplo con el cual recibo la respuesta de fail, pero no consigo acceder al mensaje. **(JS)**

```
$.ajax({
    // En data puedes utilizar un objeto JSON, un array o un query string
    data: {"descCartaPorte" : bultosIdsJSON},
    //Cambiar a type: POST si necesario
    type: "GET",
    // Formato de datos que se espera en la respuesta
    dataType: "json",
    // URL a la que se enviará la solicitud Ajax
    url: "https://api.sammer.es/descargar-carta-porte.php",
})
 .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
     }
 })
 .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
         console.log(jqXHR);
     }
});
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: El dato es un objeto dentro otro objeto, así que si el dato está en "data", el "message" está en data.error.massage

Comment: Sí, correcto, nose porque me empeñaba en que la respuesta vendría en el .fail

muchas gracias!